# How do I re-download Minecraft Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

I am playing Minecraft trial version and I have owned the full edition for over a year.

I was using my original Xbox and the original account, but it wants me to buy it again.

Comment: Try redownloading your profile. Also delete the game and redownload it. This can be fixed by relicencing, though let's just try this first.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that this has happened to multiple people, including [MonsterXRainbow](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_support/xbox_360_support/f/27/p/1009251/3020478.aspx) on XBOX support forums. I've found that the solution to this problem is going to your most recent downloads and re-downloading the game from there. Follow these steps in order to re-download the game:

1. Sign into Microsoft Live (Make sure you log in with the account in which you purchased Minecraft on!)
2. Open settings
3. Choose account, and then "download"
4. Select "Minecraft" and download the game again

Comment: I tried that but it is only showing the trial version for download as well then it wants me to "unlock full game"

Answer (score 0):

In the case that crgsqdmn's answer doesn't work, perform a license transfer.
1: Go to Settings>Account>License Transfer.
2: Perform the license transfer if eligible.
3: Go to Settings>Account>Purchase History
4: Find Minecraft.
5: Select Minecraft, then select 'Download Again.'